# Can the suffix -iĝ- be added to any noun?

Tags: translation, affixes

How free are we to add the suffix *-iĝ-* to a word when we want to give the idea that we or someone or something is becoming the thing that the word concerns? I'm not sure how else to ask the question.

An example of where I've seen something like this would be ***Kial mi Esperantistiĝis*** for ***Why I became an Esperantist***.

Here are some other example sentences:

> I want to become a cameraman: *Mi deziras kameraistiĝi* (instead of
>   *Mi deziras fariĝi kameraisto*).
>
> Ice becomes water: *Glacio akviĝas* (instead of *Glacio fariĝas
>   akvo*).

I came to this question when I was trying to think about how to translate the following sentence, which has a little different structure than the above examples.

> I was only joking about becoming an actor. *Mi nur ŝercis pri
>   ____________________.*
>
> How should the blank be filled in?

Comment: For future questions, maybe you could pass your question through this website just before posting in order to automatically replace the x-system: http://komputeko.net/konvertilo.htm

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that site. Thanks.

Comment: Even better, add to your computer a way to type them directly. See other questions for details depending on the OS. :)

Comment: Well, on the particular computer I used to type the answer, I can't since it's not mine. It would be nice, though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the root of a word falls into one of three categories. What happens when you add *iĝ* depends on the category of the root:

- Verb/Action roots: adding *iĝ* turns a transitive verb into an
  intransitive verb, e.g. *fermi* -> *fermiĝi*/*fermiĝo*
- Adjective/Quality roots: adding *iĝ* creates the meaning "to become~", 
  e.g. *granda* -> *grandiĝi*/*grandiĝo*
- Noun/Object roots: adding *iĝ*
  creates the meaning "to become a/an~", e.g. *edzo* -> *edziĝi*/*edziĝo*

More information: http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/igh.html

As for your specific sentence, I often find it awkward to translate "-ing" verbs from English, so it may be easier to say, "I was only joking when I said I wanted to become an actor" -> *Mi nur ŝercis kiam mi diris ke mi volas fariĝi aktoro/aktoriĝi* or "My desire to become an actor was just a joke" -> *Mia deziro fariĝi aktoro/aktoriĝi estis nur ŝerco*.

Comment: One can also simply use *iĝi* instead of *fariĝi*.